# How do I disable or modify auto-formatting in MVC Razor files?

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2013

I have an application in which we are using the razor engine to return XML, here is a sample of the partial view I am currently working on:

```
@{   
    var includeNamespace = ViewData["includeNamespace"] != null && (bool)ViewData["includeNamespace"];
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    <Model @{if (includeNamespace){<text>xmlns="@Html.RenderNamespace()"</text>}}>
        <DateFieldOne>@Html.EncodeDate(Model.DateFieldOne)</DateFieldOne>
        <FieldTwo>@Html.Encode(Model.FieldTwo)</FieldTwo>
        @if (Model.FieldThree != null)
        {
            <FieldThreeCollection>
                @foreach (var fieldThree in Model.FieldThree)
                {
                    <FieldThree>
                        <SubFieldOne>@Html.Encode(fieldThree.SubFieldOne)</SubFieldOne>
                        <SubDateFieldTwo>@Html.EncodeDate(fieldThree.SubDateFieldTwo)</SubDateFieldTwo>
                        <SubFieldThree>@fieldThree.SubFieldThree</SubFieldThree>
                        <SubFieldFour>@fieldThree.SubFieldFour</SubFieldFour>
                    </FieldThree>
                }
            </FieldThreeCollection>
        }
        @if (Model.CanUpdate)
        {
            <link rel="Cancel" verb="POST" href="@Html.UriHelper().BuildUri("someEndpoint/{0}/cancel", Model.Id)"/>
        }
  </Model>
}
```

The strange behavior I am seeing is when I pasted in the `@{if (includeNamespace){<text>xmlns="@Html.RenderNamespace()"</text>}}` section visual studio reformatted the view and removed all the capitalization from the xml elements; an example:

```
@{
    var includeNamespace = ViewData["includeNamespace"] != null && (bool)ViewData["includeNamespace"];
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    <model @{if (includeNamespace) { <text> xmlns="@Html.RenderNamespace()" </text> }}>
        <datefieldone>@Html.EncodeDate(Model.DateFieldOne)</datefieldone>
        <fieldtwo>@Html.Encode(Model.FieldTwo)</fieldtwo>
        @if (Model.FieldThree != null)
        {
            <fieldthreecollection>
                @foreach (var fieldThree in Model.FieldThree)
                {
                    <fieldthree>
                        <subfieldone>@Html.Encode(fieldThree.SubFieldOne)</subfieldone>
                        <subdatefieldtwo>@Html.EncodeDate(fieldThree.SubDateFieldTwo)</subdatefieldtwo>
                        <subfieldthree>@fieldThree.SubFieldThree</subfieldthree>
                        <subfieldfour>@fieldThree.SubFieldFour</subfieldfour>
                    </fieldthree>
                }
            </fieldthreecollection>
        }
        @if (Model.CanUpdate)
        {
            <link rel="Cancel" verb="POST" href="@Html.UriHelper().BuildUri("someEndpoint/{0}/cancel", Model.Id)" />
        }
    </model>
}
```

As I was typing this question I realized it did this because it is expecting html in which elements are not capitalized, so with that now in mind my question becomes: Is there any way I can stop Razor from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio formats cshtml files as html by default. In html it is standard to use lower case for the starting letter of tags. In order to change this behaviour you have to alter the settings for all HTML documents.

On the "Tools" Menu open up "Options". Then from the left expand "Text Editor/HTML/Advanced". The set "Format on Paste" to false.

Sadly I can't think of any way to disable this behaviour for a single file.

Comment: Funny enough I found that setting almost at the exact time you posted your answer.

Comment: I can't believe no one else came up with the answer sooner.

Answer (score 0):

One option to help this is to right-click the cshtml file in your solution and select "Open With..." then "Source Code (Text) Editor" (close the file first).

A more permanent fix is to open the "Options" from the "Tools" menu, select "Text Editor" then "File Extension". Then enter "cshtml" into the "Extension" box and select "Script Editor" from the list, then press "Add" then re-open your file.

The problem with this approach is you lose all intellisense capabilities.